# React-native-image-picker doesnt open camera

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native-image-picker for my app.

```
const ImageChange = () => {
        var options = {
            title: 'Select Image',
        };
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response=>{
            console.log('Response=', response)
            if(response.didCancel){
                console.log('user cancelled')
            }else if(response.error){
                console.log('picker error'+response.error)
            }else{
                let source = response
                console.log(response.uri)
            }
        })
    }
```

When I call the method by pressing an icon it shows me two options to take photo and choose from the gallery. But when I press "take photo" option it asks me permission for storage but not from camera. On calling the method again it shows me the options but when selecting "take photo" it shows an error that permissions weren't granted but choose from library works fine

I've also added these lines in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

using RN>=0.60

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This worked for me

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```